# Find children of a user supplied id in a self-join association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a functioning self-join relationship where a guideline has many children and belongs to a parent. I need to let the user supply an ID via an html form, and then find its children, or its parent (in a separate form of course) When I run in rails console as

```
@guidelines = Guideline.find(4)
@guidelines.children
```

I get the proper children, and when i do

```
@guideline.parent
```

I get the proper parent.

For some reason when I define a form as

```
<%= form_tag(guidelines_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
  <td><%= label_tag(:seeChildren, "See Immediate Children")%></td>
  <td><%= text_field_tag :seeChildren, params[:seeChildren], placeholder: "Enter ID" %></td>
  <td><%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %></td>
<% end %>
```

(app/views/index.html.erb)

And in the controller i say

```
if params[:seeChildren]
      @guideline = Guideline.find(params[:seeChildren])
      @guideline.children
```

(app/controllers/guidelines_controller.rb)

I get the following error in my rails served in Terminal:

```
    Started GET "/guidelines?utf8=%E2%9C%93&seeChildren=4" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-18 14:25:58 -0500
Processing by GuidelinesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "seeChildren"=>"4"}
  Guideline Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "guidelines".* FROM "guidelines"  WHERE "guidelines"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
  Rendered guidelines/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 85ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
    62:     <th>Guideline Text</th>
    63:   </tr>
    64: 
    65:   <% @guidelines.each do |guideline| %>
    66:     <tr>
    67:       <td><%= guideline.id %></td>
    68:       <td><%= guideline.guide_desc %></td>
  app/views/guidelines/index.html.erb:65:in `_app_views_guidelines_index_html_erb__3376611479089996349_70360485758280'


  Rendered /Users/john.dodson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/john.dodson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/john.dodson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (21.6ms)
```

Any ideas? I appreciate the help. Ive posted a couple questions and was unsuccessful usually because I wasn't supplying enough information, so please let me know if you need to see another file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to using the wrong singular/plural on guidelines, I found out that I needed to cast a single object into an array. So find a guideline, then call children and cast the results into an array. so in the controller I say:

```
if params[:seeChildren]
      @guideline = Guideline.find(params[:seeChildren])
      @guidelines = Array.wrap(@guideline.children())
```

and magic, my query works. Posting this here so other people having a similar problem can find the truth.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have forgotten to define `@guidlines` in your controller, which would explain why you are getting the `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` error message when attempting to call `.each` on **@guidelines** in `<% @guidelines.each do |guideline| %>`

Comment: Well I did define it as in my question, but it's obviously the wrong way to define it.

Comment: No, you're not defining it. You're defining singular and calling `each` on plural.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Same as JBMILGROm said, you forgot to mention @guidelines in controller.